# My hopper doesnt work even i make sure it pointed to the chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

hello i am having trouble with my hopper it doesnt transfer items to chest or furnace. I did shift+right/left click, i tried other stuffs i could that possibly could make it work but it doesnt. it transfer item if i put another hopper to it but doesnt transfer to chest and from chest doesnt transfer to the hopper. 
[image]

[image]

i don't know what i did wrong. pls help me and excuse my english

Comment: What are the "other stuffs" you have tried?

Comment: Is there a redstone torch or other power source below the pink wool? Or is the chest maybe just full?

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem you probably have. Read below of how a hopper works

> A hopper has three function (without any redstone source)
> 1.Collect item entities (free-floating items in the world) into its inventory from the space above it
> 2. Get a single item into its inventory from a container above it
>  3. Move a single item from its own inventory into a container it's facing

-Minecraft Gamepedia
Try putting the hopper in again, or put the hopper on top of the chest,

Comment: Yes, they are, clearly visible in the image.

Comment: Could you provide a view from the top using spectator mode?

Comment: No, because I'm not the same person as the one who asked the question. But the left hopper clearly points left.

Comment: Answer is edited to better suit the question.